# Passing character as variable name in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to solve an implicit equation in R using `multiroot` function from package `rootSolve`.

I am reading the implicit equation from a text file using `parse`. Also, the variable to be solved for is read from a text file as a character.

For using `multiroot`,

```
multiroot(function, initial_guess, ....))
```

we have to generate a function from the read equation. I did this by

```
fun <- function(op) {fun <- eval(expr.im)}
op = as.name(opim.names)
```

where `expr.im` is the read implicit equation as an expression from the text file, and `opim.names` is the variable to be solved for, as character.

But the problem arises when I pass the variable `op` to be solved as a symbol to the function. It gives an error saying that the object

> "variable to be solved for" not found.

I think that the variable symbol is not being passed correctly in the function.

Please tell me how to do it correctly.

Since a lot of stuff is going on in my code, I cannot post the whole thing here.
Let me just state a small example for it.

```
var.name = "x1" # This is what I read from the text file #
var.sym = as.name(var.name)

func <- function(var.sym){
func = x1^2      # the expression x1^2 is also read from a text file  #
}                  # I am trying to solve the implicit equation x1^2 = 0  #
initial_guess = 1
root = multiroot(f=func, start = initial_guess)
```

As requested by nicola here's what I want - 
I have a text file giving me the name of the variable and its initial guess.
I read the variable name (say "x") and the initial guess value (say 1) into variables `var` (character) and `guess`(numeric).
I also have another text file containing the following equation -

```
x^3-1
```

I read this as an expression in the variable `expr`.

I want to find the solution to the implicit equation `expr`.
(The text files can have different names of variables and correspondingly an implicit expression in another file)

As you know, for using the multiroot function, we need to have a function.
The problem is I am not able to pass the variable name stored in `var` to the function.

Any further clarification will be given if asked.

Comment: The second argument of `multiroot` should be a numeric vector. Why are you passing symbols? Give more information and try to build a reproducible example. It's very likely you are using `multiroot` wrong.

Comment: @nicola  'multiroot' function takes in guess values as second argument. I am giving the guess values correctly.  I am trying to pass the variable name (which I read from a file as a string) into a function.

Comment: You are not defining the function `func` correctly. There are several issues in that definition. The `var.sym` line doesn't add anything to the function definition; are you aware of the difference between an object and an argument of the function? Just define `func<-function(x) x^2` and your example works.

Comment: @nicola As you can see from the code the expression and the variable are user defined. I am reading them from a file supplied by the user. Thus I cannot just write    'func<-function(x) x^2'. I am trying to write a more generic code.

Comment: If there is any other way to do what I want to do, I am all ears.

Comment: Ok, provide an example of your input and your desired output. I guess  what you are looking for should be doable, but you need to give precise details. Here we need the `character` vector which defines the variables and the one which defines the body of the function to solve.

Comment: @nicola Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your function in the following way.

```
#input: function expression, variable names and initial guess
expr<-"x^3-1"
var.name<-"x"
initial.guess<-2
#we build an "empty" function
func<-function() {}
#now we set the formal arguments and the body of the function
formals(func)<-eval(parse(text=paste0("alist(",paste(var.name,collapse="=,"),"=)")))
body(func)<-parse(text=expr)
#we can see that func is correctly defined
func
#function (x) 
#x^3 - 1
#now we can call multiroot
multiroot(func,initial.guess)
#$root
#[1] 1
#$f.root
#[1] 3.733019e-08
#$iter
#[1] 6
#$estim.precis
#[1] 3.733019e-08
```

You need a little more care if you are dealing with function of more than one variable. See `?multiroot` to check how to pass the arguments. Basically you have to pass just one argument which is a vector of all the function arguments. It shouldn't be difficult if you take some time to see how I managed to build `func`. If you are exclusively dealing with one variable function, you should use the base `uniroot` function.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You cant imagine how much this has helped me in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to understand the description fully. But to answer the heading, you can try this procedure-

```
a = "random_string"
b = "a"
eval(parse(text = b))
[1] "random_string"
```